# Kendo UI Mobile Refresh List View on View Show

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm working on a Kendo UI Mobile app (using only iOS at the time) and currently have 3 views in the app.  The "main" view has a ListView, and the other 2 views are simple forms.

The list view is bound to data that I have in Local Storage and have a method for getting the data.  It all seems to be working fine when the app loads, and I can also do a "pull to refresh" and the data will update.

What I can't figure out is how to refresh the list when the view is essentially re-shown.  A user can go to one of the other views and do some sort of action which will update the data so when they go back to the list view, I would like the data to be automatically refreshed.

Hopefully this makes sense?  I've included my `appInit` method below which is what's binding the data initially:

```
function appInit() {
        $("#certificateList").kendoMobileListView({
            pullToRefresh: true,
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: function(options) {
                        var data = Redemptions.getCertificates();
                        options.success(data);
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: 'id',
                            fields: {
                                id: { type: 'number' },
                                value: { type: 'number', format: '{c2}' }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }),
            //dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({data: Redemptions.getCertificates() }),
            template: $("#certificateTemplate").html()
        });
    }
```

**Things I've tried**

- Using a method attached to the `data-after-show` on the main view
- Calling `$('#certificateList').data('kendoMobileListView').refresh();` after my "add" code completes and navigates back to the main view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I also needed to add a `read()` on the `DataSource` for the ListView.  My resulting code is:

```
function refreshCertificates() {
    var certificateList = $('#certificateList').data('kendoMobileListView');
    certificateList.dataSource.read();   // added line
    certificateList.refresh();
}
```

It would be called from something such as:

```
if (cert.Status === 1) { // valid
    app.navigate('#certificatesView', 'slide:right');
    refreshCertificates();
}
```

I chose to not have it be in the `data-after-show` attribute because there are times when I perform an action when the view doesn't actually get refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo mobile views have an event, beforeShow. You should be able to add an eventhandler for this, and do whatever you need to before the view is shown.

```
<div id="mainView" data-role="view" data-title="Main Page" data-before-show="mainViewLoad" data-layout="default">

function mainViewLoad() { 
    alert("Main View loaded"); 
}
```

See jsbin http://jsbin.com/OBeZeZu/1/edit

Kendo View Events list here  http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/view#events

Comment: The problem I ran into with that before is the list within the View doesn't seem to be "available" (not the right word but can't think of the proper term at the moment).  It says method `refresh()` is not available on `var certificateList = $('#certificateList').data('kendoMobileListView');`

Comment: When are you creating the ListView object, at document ready, or on the application init ? You could try after-show as a last resort, or possible the before-show but with a setTimeout($("#listView").data("kendoListView").refresh(), 200);

Comment: I have the UL created and then am wiring the ListView up on app init.  I didn't think about the `setTimeout()` though, I think I'll give that a shot. Thanks!